# Whatsapp URL scheme does not allow query parametrs in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, whatsapp

I am not able to share any link which has query parameters like second one.

`whatsapp://send?abid=2&text=http://www.google.com`  WORKS FINE

`whatsapp://send?abid=2&text=http://www.google.com/?search=123`  DOES NOT WORK

Comment: Have you tried encoding the text http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: yup.. I am sending the whole string to NSURL after encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `?` for sending any parameter after the first one.

To pass the value of the search as 123 try using `&search=123` rather than `?search=123`.

If the  `http://www.google.com/?search=123`    is a whole string then you have to encode it as that contains "?" , "/" and ":".

Your text value would be like this:

```
whatsapp://send?abid=2&text=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fsearch%3D123
```

which is the encoded string of the above.
Maybe this could solve your problem.

Comment: Was this successfully? Because when I try adding query parameters, my string automatically cuts off at '&' of '?'..